# SocketIO on connection not firing?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to establish a simple connection between a socket.io on a .php page and a node.js server, unfortinately it wont work? the .on('connection') doesn't fire on the server side code?

All the questions I see use express, I do not want to use express..

Client side:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.7.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = new io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:1904');

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
});
// Add a connect listener
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
});
// Add a disconnect listener
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('The client has disconnected!');
});

// Sends a message to the server via sockets
function sendMessageToServer(message) {
    socket.send(message);
};
</script>
```

Server side:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(1904);
console.log('Server started.');

var io = require('socket.io')(server, {});

io.sockets.on('connecton', function(socket) {
    console.log('A new player connected.');

    socket.on('happy', function(data) {
        console.log('happy because: ' + data.reason);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the routine I use for all my socket-based node projects, Hope this helps you out.  Let me know if you have any other questions I can help with.

file named server.js:

```
var http = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3001');
});

//for testing, we're just going to send data to the client every second
setInterval( function() {
    var msg = Math.random();
    io.emit('message', msg);
    console.log (msg);

}, 1000);
```

file named index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">            </script>   
<!-- UPDATE THE FOLLOWING TO THE PATH TO YOUR SOCKET.IO.JS FILE OR USE CDN -->
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').css('width', '100%');
        $('div').css('text-align', 'center').css('width', '100%')
        $('#message').css('font-size', '2em');


        // DEFINE OUR SOCKET...
        var socket = io();


        // EVERY TIME THE NODE.JS SERVER SENDS US 'MESSAGE' WE'LL DISPLAY THAT UPDATED NUMBER IN A DIV
        socket.on('message', function(msg){
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg;
        });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="message"></div>

</body>
</html>
```